# Can a 12v dry relay be able to handle 24v load with its own PSU?

Tags: relay

i have this door access controller

https://zktecousa.com/product/c3-200-access-control-panel/#section-3

and on the DOOR CONTROLLER terminals where the relay works on, I wanted to attach a 24v light on it instead of a magnetic lock. I will be supplying separate 24v power to the light (power wont come from the access control board's 12v psu)

So technically i'll just be using the NO and COM terminals to trigger my lights.

Is this alright? or will i blow out the relay or board?

pretty much looks like this

[image]

Comment: you'll need to check the power rating of your light and make sure that the relay can handle the current passing through it.

Answer (score 2):

It should be okay, but I would strongly suggest looking up the part number on the relay itself and double checking with the relay's datasheet. The link provided claims "FORM-C relay output-SPDT 5A@12V DC".

Generally, the coil voltage and the switching voltage are spec'd differently. A Form-C relay with a 12VDC coil could have a switching voltage rated for 250VAC/30VDC @ 5A. The exact rating for the switching voltage would be found in the relay's datasheet.

Answer (score -1):

If the relays on the board (Square boxes above the connector) are meant for 12V contact rating, using 24V will not end well. If they are rated for higher, then you could possibly, assuming there is nothing connected to the traces that would not like 24V. Say a diode or capacitor.

Easiest thing would be to use the onboard relay and the onboard 12V power source, to trigger a second relay that has a 12V coil rating and 24V contact rating.

In both cases, you also have to make sure the load current fits the relay you are using.

Comment: I like the Secondary relay strategy... i think that is a great 2nd option if the current on-board relays aren't enough for 24v current passing thru it. 

ps, i dont know why your answer got down voted lol i upvoted it

Comment: @BrownChiLD oh, just a couple of questionable voters on here. It happens. I don't even notice it any more. Glad you think it's a good idea.